# A value of type 'OAuthCredential' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GoogleAuthCredential'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, googlesigninaccount

This is my code for google sign-in ..

```
             onPressed: () async{
                final GoogleSignInAccount newuser= await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
                final  GoogleSignInAuthentication newuserauth= await 
         googleUser.authentication;
                final GoogleAuthCredential cred= GoogleAuthProvider.credential(accessToken: 
                 newuserauth.accessToken,idToken: newuserauth.idToken);
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(cred);
              },
```

And the errors i am getting are as follows..

```
        error: A value of type 'OAuthCredential' can't be assigned to a variable of type 
        'GoogleAuthCredential'. (invalid_assignment at [firebase] lib\firstpage.dart:147)

        error: Undefined name 'googleUser'. (undefined_identifier at [firebase] 
            lib\firstpage.dart:145)
         error: A value of type 'GoogleSignInAccount?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 
        'GoogleSignInAccount'. (invalid_assignment at [firebase] lib\firstpage.dart:144)
```

These are the dependencies in my pubspec.yaml..

```
      dependencies:
        flutter:
          sdk: flutter
           firebase_auth: ^3.2.0
           firebase_core : ^1.10.0
           flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
           cloud_firestore: ^3.1.0
           google_sign_in: ^5.2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple problems in you code as follows:

Line 2 : `GoogleSignIn().signIn()` returns `GoogleSignInAccount?` which mean it could be null but you're using `GoogleSignInAccount` which mean it can't be null,,, so change it to (This is the last error you got):

```
   final GoogleSignInAccount? newuser= await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
```

Line 3 & 4: You used the variable name `newuser` not `googleUser` change one of them (the second error)

Line 5 & 6: `GoogleAuthProvider.credential(..)` returns `OAuthCredential` not `GoogleAuthCredential` and that is the first error you got.

However, with `final` you don't need to specify the variable type which is one of the Dart advantages.

Moreover, you'll get error on `newuser.authentication` because newuser, as mentioned before, could be null so you can't access `authentication`... the way I love to do it, because I don't like to deal with null values is to return from the function before using it if its null.

So the whole code would be (I added the types so you could see the difference, but you don't need them ):

```
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
if (googleUser == null) return null;
  
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
final OAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
```